# Saving Player Data in RLua

Tags: lua, roblox

Is there a reason why these do not work?

Player joining script:

```
local DataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("GeneralStats")


game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)

    local stats = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local points = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    points.Name = "Points"

    local credits = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    credits.Name = "Credits"    

    local key = "player-"..player.userId

    local savedValues = DataStore:GetAsync(key)

    if savedValues then
        --Save format: (points, credits)
        points.Value = savedValues[1]
        credits.Value = savedValues[2]
    else
        local ValuesToSave = {points.Value, credits.Value}
        DataStore:SetAsync(key, ValuesToSave)
    end


end)
```

And this other script for when the player leaves.

```
local DataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("GeneralStats")

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:connect(function(player)

    local key = "player-"..player.userId    

    --Save key: {points, credits}
    local valuesToSave = {player.leaderstats.Points.Values, player.leaderstats.Credits.Values}
    DataStore:SetAsync(key, valuesToSave)

end)
```

This is for a game I am working on, justify (`RLua` is `Roblox Lua`, if you didn't know).

Comment: would you share what you expect the code to do and what it does instead?

Comment: Trying to clarify. corrected grammar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, more than likely the leaderstat is being removed before you have a chance to extract data.

I would suggest not using leaderstats as reference for data. It's better to store data on the script directly.

However, if you truly must use leaderstats, parent it to somewhere else, extract data, then remove it.

```
local lead = player.leaderstats
lead.Parent = game
-- extract data
lead:Destroy()
```

Or you could define all those objects in a variable before they get reparented.

But again, I highly suggest not to use leaderstats for data saving. Exploiters can change that data easily and change the value to a high number.